# If exists an Eigenspace $V_{\lambda}$ with dim($V_{\lambda}) \geq 2$, the $f$-invariant subspaces are infinite

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace, generalized-eigenvector

Let $V$ a $\mathbb{K}$-vectorial space,with char($\mathbb{K}$) = 0.

Is it true that if exists an Eigenspace $V_{\lambda} \subset V$, with dim($V_{\lambda})\geq 2$, the $f-$invariant subspaces are infinite ?

If so,for which dimension ?

Any help or sketch of the proof would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to parse what you've written. Am I right that the thing you want to prove is "if $f: V \to V$ is a linear map with an eigenspace $V_\lambda$ of dimension at least $2$ then $f$ has infinitely many invariant subspaces"?

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes,if the statment is true, for which dimension ?

Comment: What do you mean "for which dimension"? Dimension of what? The statement is true as long as $\dim(V_\lambda)\geq 2$.

Comment: @Wojowu Dimension of invariant subspaces, there exist infinite invariant subspace of every dimension ?

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment below your question, the question you seem to be asking is

> If $f: V \to V$ is a linear map with an eigenspace $V_{\lambda}$ of dimension at least $2$, then $f$ has infinitely many invariant subspaces.

The answer to this question is yes.  Note that if $V_{\lambda}$ is an eigenspace, then any subspace $U \subset V_\lambda$ is an eigenspace and thus an $f$-invariant subspace.

If $V_{\lambda}$ has dimension at least $2$, then we can find infinitely many one-dimensional subspaces $U$. One construction of such a family of subspaces is as follows: suppose that $v_1,\dots,v_d$ is a basis of $V_{\lambda}$.  For $t \in \Bbb K$, define
$$
U_t = \operatorname{span}(\{v_1 + tv_2\}).
$$
Note that if $t_1 \neq t_2$, then $U_{t_1} \neq U_{t_2}$.

---

We can extend this construction as follows.  For any $k < d = \dim(V_{\lambda})$, define 
$$
U_t = \operatorname{span}(\{v_1 + tv_2,v_3,\dots, v_{k+1}\}).
$$

Comment: This prove only one-dimensional subspaces, what about higher dimensions?

Comment: For any $d < \dim V_{\lambda}$, $V_{\lambda}$ contains infinitely many subspaces of dimension $d$.